# Can I get the url parameters in html when I use webview.loadUrl()?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

Here is my code:

```
private WebView mWebView;
String testValue="hello";
mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.64.13:8079/ctms-logistics/demo.html?test="+testValue);
```

and I want to get the value of parameter "test"(which is the value of variable testValue) from the url in my demo.js which included in demo.html, how? I know in browser we can use window.location.hash to get the url, but it doesn't work in webview.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the function inside your js which will accept these parameters. And call that function from activity as shown below

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.64.13:8079/ctms-logistics/demo.html?test="+testValue);
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                   mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setTestValue("+testValue+")");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have figured out this method too, but I regard it as a kind of alternative method. I have found the answer for my question, it is that use window.location.href to get the url from webview.loadUrl, and then parse that url to get the parameter I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for my question, it is that use window.location.href to get the url from webview.loadUrl, and then parse that url to get the parameter I want. it is like this:

```
function getParamHref(paramName) {
var href = window.location.href;
var search = href.substr(href.indexOf("?") + 1, href.length);
var reg = new RegExp("(^|&)" + paramName + "=([^&]*)(&|$)", "i");
var r = search.match(reg);
if (!isUndeFinedOrNull(r)) return unescape(r[2]);
return null;
```

}

if I want to get the parameter "test" from the url, then I can call the method getParamHref("test") at the begining of my demo.js file.